# angular2: Reference one config parameter from another and use in html

Tags: angular, environment-variables

In the configuration file, can I reference one config from another? I am using `environment.ts` file.

```
    export const environment = {
     production: false,

    //Configuration parameters
     CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MINSIZE: 5,
     CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MAXSIZE: 20,
     CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_VALUE_MINSIZE: 5,
     CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_VALUE_MAXSIZE: 20,

      NEWTEST: "minimum size of text value is" + 
        this.CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MINSIZE
   };
```

Comment: I see that i am getting the following output "minimum size of text value is"undefined

Comment: What exactly is the question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MINSIZE = 5;

export const environment = {
  production: false,

  // Configuration parameters
  CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MINSIZE,
  CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MAXSIZE: 20,
  CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_VALUE_MINSIZE: 5,
  CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_VALUE_MAXSIZE: 20,

  NEWTEST: `minimum size of text value is ${CONFIG_ADMIN_CREATE_KEY_MINSIZE}`
};
```